# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)x^2y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)x^2y^2}$$

how should I approach this?

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)}=0$$ but I still have $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1}{x^2y^2}$$

The answer says there is no limit

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
So in there is a neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0)$ where $\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\geq \frac{1}{4}.$

Hence, for $x\not=0$, $y\not=0$ and $(x,y)\in U$,
$$\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)x^2y^2}=\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\cdot \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2y^2}\geq \frac{1}{4}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}\right)\to +\infty$$
as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to polar

$\lim_\limits{r\to 0} \frac {1-\cos r^2}{r^6 \sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}$

if this limit equals 0 then the limit will exist and your function will be continuous.
If it depends on theta then it will not as different points around near the origin will have different values.

And you have reduced the limit to the analysis of a single variable.

Comment: At the denominator you should have $r^6$. This is crucial for the evaluation of the limit.

Comment: @RobertZ indeed you are correct and I will fix it.  But with that change the the answer becomes more obvious.

Comment: It will depend only on $r$ since there is no theta makes $(\cos\theta,\sin \theta)=(0,0)$, (orthogonal functions). So, as posted in Doug M solution you need to use L'Hosiptal rule six times you get the answer which is zero.

Comment: @mwomath if $r$ is arbitrarily close to  $0$ any $\theta$ makes $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ close to $(0,0)$ And L'Hopital's is not necessary, and the limit does not exist.

Comment: I was thinking in this case, but we can avoid this by imagine that as a complex number $z=x+iy=(x,y)$; and the complex number does not have polar form in case $r=0$.

Comment: You are right! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2\sin^2\left (\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$$

Comment: I know what you mean, but writing "$\to (x^2+y^2)/2$" is not well defined.